# Prevent malicious vulnerability scan increasing load on a server

Tags: vulnerabilities

this week we have been suffering some malicious vulnerability scans to our servers, increasing the load on them, making them nearly unusable.

The attack is easy to defend, just blocking the offending ip, but only after discovering it.

Is there any form of prevent it? Is it normal that one server becomes nearly unusable due to one of these scans?

These are the requests done in just one second to our server:

```
    [Fri Mar 12 19:15:27 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/zope trunk 2
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/8872fcacd7663c040f0149ed49f572e9
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/188201
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/74e118780caa0f5232d6ec393b47ae01
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/87d4b821b2b6b9706ba6c2950c0eaefd
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/138917
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/180377
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/182712
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/compl2s
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/e7ba351f0ab1f32b532ec679ac7d589d
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/184530
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/compl_s
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/55542
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/7b9d5a65aab84640c6414a85cae2c6ff
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/77257
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/157611
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/textwrapping
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/51713
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/elina
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/fd4800093500f7a9cc21bea232658706
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/59719
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/administrationexamples
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/29587
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/bdebc9c4aa95b3651e9b8fd90c015327
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/defaultchangenotetext
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/figments
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/69744
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/fastpixelperfect
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/conchmusicsoundtoolkit
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/settingwindowposition
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/windowresizing
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/84784
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/186114
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/99858
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/131677
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/167783
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/99933
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/3en17ljttc
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/gradientcode
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pythondevelopmentandnavigationwithspe
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/10546
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/167932
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/smallerrectforspritecollision
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/176292
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/3sumvid-19yroldfuckedby2bigcocks
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/67909
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/175185
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/131319
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/99900
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/act5
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/contributors-agreement
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/128447
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/71052
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/114242
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/69768
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/debuggingwithwinpdbfromwithinspe
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/39360
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/176267
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/143468
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/140202
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/25268
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/82241
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/142920
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/downloadingipythonformswindows
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/34367
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/for_collaborators
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pydeveclipseextensionsfabio
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/usingpdbinipython
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/142264
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/49003
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/gamelets
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/texturecoordinatearithmetic
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/project_interface
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/143177
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pydeveclipsefabio
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/91525
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/40426
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/134819
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/usingipythonwithtextpad
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/developingpythoninipython
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/35569
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/objfileloader
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/simpleopengl2dclasses
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/191495
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/3dvilla
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/145368
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/140118
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/87799
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/142320
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/glslexample
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/39826
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cairopygame
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/191338
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/91819
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/152003
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/gllight
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/40567
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/137877
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/188209
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/84577
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/131017
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/fightnight
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/79781
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/4731669
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/161942
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/160289
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/81594
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/12127
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/164452
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/96823
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/163598
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/159190
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-test fsfs+ra_local
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/davros
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-publish logs
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-cleanup
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-test fsfs+ra_svn
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cdrwin_v3
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/brianpensive
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/x86-openbsd shared gcc
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/roundup-0
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/svcastle
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/56584
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/45934
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-build
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/97194
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cdrwin_3
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/72243
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/117043
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/147084
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/52713
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/101489
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/134867
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/win32-dependencies
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/36548
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/43827
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/100791
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/elita_posing
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/167848
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/36314
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/49951
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/142740
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cdromkiteletronicaptg
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/138060
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/68483
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/184474
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/137447
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/sndarray
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/127870
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/167312
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/75411
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/167969
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/surfarray
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/174941
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/59129
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/147554
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/105577
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/91734
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/96679
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/06au
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/124495
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/aah
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/164439
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/12638190
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/eliel
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/171164
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/linearinterpolator
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-test
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/heading_news
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/87778
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/portlet_64568222
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/graphic_ep
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/132230
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/12251
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/greencheese
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/188966
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cdsonic
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/171522
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/elitewrap
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/184313
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/188079
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/147511
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/160952
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/132581
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/84885
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/graphic_desktop
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/win32-xp vs2005
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/128548
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/92057
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/65235
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pyscgi
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/56926
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/svcastle-big
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/138553
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/138232
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/153367
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/42315
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/150012
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/160079
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/win32-xp vc60
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/163482
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/42642
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/174458
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/163109
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/spacer_greys
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pdf_icon16
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/26346
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/190998
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/fforigins
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/aliens-0
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/step-update faad
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/13376
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/52647
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/155036
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/compl2
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/174323
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/42317
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tsugumo
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/171850
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/184127
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/48321
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/162545
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/84180
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/135901
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/57817
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/6360574
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/124989
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/113314
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/sprite-tutorial
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/14294
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/191387
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/187294
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/178666
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/179653
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/wingide-users
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/16309095
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/169465
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/189399
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/172392
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/35627
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/2670901
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/177847
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/chimplinebyline
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/87518
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/154595
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/12811780
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cdmenupro42
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/110131
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/95615
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/18464
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/lwedchoice-1999
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/5099582
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/100968
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/j-emacs
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:28 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/0206mathew
[Fri Mar 12 19:15:29 2010] [error] [client 213.37.49.231] File does not exist: /var/www/html/10844356
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup something like [fail2bain](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to immediately block the hosts doing the scanning through the system firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're seeing a vulnerability scan.  The log entries you've pasted are not typical of any types of vulnerability probes I've ever encountered.  It may be worth putting some extra time into trying to figure out what's actually going on (take a look at the user-agent and referrer strings).

Probably the easiest thing would be a quick script that watches the log file and keeps count of how many times it's seen the same IP address in the last n seconds.  Once it passes an arbitrarily selected threshole, it triggers adding an iptables rule.